# node.js Stream Response on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, node-streams

I have a simple node.js web service at AWS (EC2):

```
async generate(ctx) {
    ctx.body = await this.pdfGenerator.generate(ctx.request.body)

    let documentName = Date.now()

    ctx.set({
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${documentName}.pdf`,
        'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary'
    })
}
```

The PDF generator is simply return a promise with Stream type (`Promise<ReadableStream>`). The problem is, I cannot get this response somehow. JSON response works, but stream response doesn't. What should I do / check to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: What framework are you using there?